# Hexadecimal number comparison?

Tags: c, hex

I'm a new to C language and a bit confused about how hexadecimal, decimal numbers work. I am trying to work with maximum of 4 bytes, so 0xFFFFFFFF. I basically want the program to give an alert if any number is entered with 9 digits or higher. I have written a code as below but it still lets me input numbers bigger than 0xFFFFFFFF. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
int main()
{
uint32_t rgba;
printf("Enter rgba value: ");
scanf("%x", &rgba);
if (rgba > 0xFFFFFFFF){
    printf("Maximum number of 8 digits!\n");
}
else{
    rgba_values(rgba);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot check for a number larger than it is possible to *store*. The 'too large value' never gets stored in the target variable. If you want to allow entering this *but* next prevent it, use a larger type or a string for input.

Comment: I see your point but i define the variable as 32 bit, if I enter something bigger shouldn't there be an automatic error then?

Comment: [The `man` page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) states that in case of an error, `errno` should be set to `ERANGE` and `scanf` should return `EOF`. But you don't check its return value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Jongware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2564301/jongware) commented, "You cannot check for a number larger than it is possible to store."

To detect if user input is outside the range of `uint32_t rgba`, code needs to understand that the user input has or will exceed that range.

Method 1: Use larger integer type:  This method will detect "100000000" as too large an input, but will have trouble with numbers larger than "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF".

```
unsigned long long UserInput;
uint32_t rgba;
printf("Enter rgba value: ");
if (scanf("%llx", &UserInput) != 1) {
  puts("EOF or Scan Failure");
  return 1;
}
if (UserInput > 0xFFFFFFFFu) {
  puts("Range error");
  return 1;
}
rgba = UserInput;
rgba_values(rgba);
```

Method 2: Use `fgets()/strtoul()`.  The following will work for input up to 99 `char` long (which includes the `'\n'`).

```
uint32_t rgba;
char *buf[100];
printf("Enter rgba value: ");
if(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL)  {
  puts("EOF");
  return 1;
}
char *endptr = 0;
errno = 0;
unsigned long ul = strtoul(buf, &endptr, 16);
if (buf == endptr) {
  puts("No conversion");
  return 1;
}
if (errno || ul > 0xFFFFFFFFu) {
  puts("value out of range");
  return 1;
}
rgba = (uint32_t) ul;
rgba_values(rgba);
```

Other methods include counting the number of hexadecimal characters or converting user input 1 `char` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (rgba > 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

`rgba` is a 32-bit unsigned integer value, the condition above is always false. A 32-bit unsigned integer value is always <= 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Sorry I think there is a misunderstanding, when I say scanf("%x", &rgba); it lets me enter a value in hexadecimal. Lets say I entered 123456789 which has 9 digits, I want it to give the message in that case. But it doesn't give the "Maximum number of 8 digits" message, instead it jumps to rgba_values function.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store the user-input into a char* first:

```
char rgba_str[20]; // 20 is an arbitrary larger buffer size
printf("Enter rgba value: ");
scanf("%s", &rgba_str);
```

Then check and see if the length of the string is greater than 9 digits:

```
if ( strlen( rgba_str ) > 8 )
  // Error
```

If not, turn rgba_str into a hexadecimal integer:

```
else
  rgba = strtoul(rgba_str, NULL, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `scanf`: it returns 1 if and only if the input is a valid hexadecimal number without overflow.  Note that this will only fit your purpose if the `int` is exactly 32 bits on your platform.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true -- reading an unsigned number (as with `%x`) will read arbitrarily large numbers and reduce them mod 2<sup>n</sup>.  Signed numbers (`%d`) cause undefined behavior on overflow.  In neither case will scanf (necessarily) return a useful error code.  Nevertheless, you should always check the return value of `scanf` to catch completely invalid inputs.

Comment: My bad! `scanf` is almost completely useless!  `strtoul` would check for overflow but longs are not necessarily 32 bits.  Reading a string, checking for a maximum of 8 hex digits, ignoring initial `'0'`s and passing it to `strtoul` seems to be the preferred solution.